# Relative pronouns for "und" and "oder" with two singular nouns?

Tags: grammatical-number, relative-clause, relative-pronoun

So from what I've gathered:

- With "und" you use "die" as in plural (third person plural). For example:

> Ich suche nach einer Katze und einem Hund, die mich für immer lieben werden.
>   -> (sie/die Katze und der Hund)
>
> Das sind Clara und Zoey, die uns gestern das Geld gestohlen haben. -> (sie/Clara und Zoey)

- With "oder" you use the nearest noun to the relative pronoun, because you're referring to just one. For example:

> Ich suche nach einem Mädchen oder einem Jungen, der(...) -> (der Junge)
>
> Ich suche nach einem Jungen oder einem Mädchen, das(...) -> (das Mädchen)
>
> Man muss eine Ablenkung oder ein Hobby finden, mit dem(...) -> (das Hobby)
>
> Man muss ein Hobby oder eine Ablenkung finden, mit der(...) -> (die Ablenkung)

Can somebody please tell me if that's correct or not? Thanks!

Comment: This is a duplicate, at least tbe part with *oder*. I know because I asked it, under a different name though. I'm gladly using "bzw." since, but only in writing. Otherwise, *Junge oder Mädchen* = *Kind*, *ein Kind, das*.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such thing in German. The most common way to do this is to insert both pronouns respectively:

> Ich suche nach einem Mädchen oder einem Jungen, das oder der ...
>
> Man muss eine Ablenkung oder ein Hobby finden, mit der oder mit dem ...

In the relative clause, it is also possible to use *beziehungsweise*:

> Ich suche nach einem Mädchen oder einem Jungen, das beziehungsweise der ...
>
> Man muss eine Ablenkung oder ein Hobby finden, mit der beziehungsweise mit dem ...

Comment: Okay, got it. The "und" part is however correct right?

Comment: @jenns Yes, "und" implies a plural.