# Relativpronomen (Numerus + Genus) nach "oder"

Tags: relative-clause, relative-pronoun

Das Relativpronomen wird ja in Genus und Numerus an das Bezugswort angepasst, auf das es sich bezieht. Das heißt:

> Das Buch, das für uns relevant ist, ist schlecht geschrieben.

> Der Zeitungsartikel, der für uns relevant ist, ist schlecht geschrieben.

> Die Bücher, die für uns relevant sind, sind schlecht geschrieben.

Wenn ich jetzt zwei Bezugspunkte habe, die durch ein "und" verknüpft sind, klappt das auch:

> Das Buch und der Zeitungsartikel, die für uns relevant sind, laufen nicht gut.

Wie sieht das jetzt bei einer Verknüfung von "oder" aus?

> Das Buch oder der Zeitungsartikel, ?

Wir beziehen uns eigentlich ja nur auf *ein* Objekt, also ist der Numerus eigentlich Singular, aber dann ist das Geschlecht natürlich nicht eindeutig. Spontan hätte ich immer auch Plural verwendet, also

> Das Buch oder der Zeitungsartikel, die für uns relevant sind, ...

Ich meine aber auch Konstruktionen wie folgende gesehen zu haben:

> Das Buch oder der Zeitungsartikel, der oder die für uns relevant ist/sind, ...

Was ist die offiziell richtige Form? Wie lässt sich das herleiten?

Comment: Worum diese Frage eigentlich geht ist jedem Programmierer als inklusives oder exklusives oder bekannt. Dazu gibt es hier bereits einige Fragen. Ich habe gerade nur keine Zeit zu suchen, ob ein Duplikat dabei ist, aber es scheint mir so.

Comment: ... Welchen Grund kann es geben, auf keinen Fall sagen zu wollen, ob nun das Buch oder der Artikel schlecht geschrieben ist? Oder es nicht zu wissen und aus diesem Grund nicht sagen zu können - obwohl das betreffende Objekt für uns "relevant" ist? Welchen Grund könnte es überhaupt geben, über ein Printprodukt, auf dessen Identität ich mich nicht festlegen will oder kann, obwohl es "für und relevant ist", nun ausgerechnet sagen zu wollen, das es "schlecht geschrieben" ist? Vielleicht werden ja in Redaktionssitzungen Logicals gespielt, wer weiß.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Im Allgemeinen gilt die Regel (Siehe auch "Duden: Grammatik", Randnummer 1594), dass bei einem additiven Verhältnis ("und"), das sich aus der Konjunktion ergibt, das Verb im Plural zu stehen hat. Da Relativpronomen und Verb kongruent sein müssen, steht das eben auch im Plural.

Bei einem nicht (oder nicht eindeutigen) additiven Verhältnis ("oder")  richtet sich das Verb nach dem *näher stehenden* Nomen. Allerdings "bindet" das Relativpronomen an das zugehörige Nomen stärker:

> Der Zeitungsartikel oder das Buch, die für uns relevant sind, müssen zurückgegeben werden.

(Sowohl Zeitungsartikel als auch Buch sind für uns relevant.)

> Der Zeitungsartikel oder das Buch, das für uns relevant ist, muss zurückgegeben werden.

(Nur das Buch ist für uns relevant)

> Entweder der Zeitungsartikel oder das Buch, die [beide] für uns relevant sind, muss zurückgegeben werden.

(Beide sind für uns relevant, aber man muss - "exklusives oder" durch "entweder" - eins von beiden zurückgeben)

Um wirklich auszudrücken, dass sowohl Buch als auch Zeitungsartikel relevant sind, muss der Relativsatz im Plural stehen - ansonsten bindet der Relativsatz nur an das näherstehende Nomen.

Mehrdeutig wird diese Konstruktion, wenn eins der Nomen selbst schon im Plural steht:

> Der Zeitungsartikel oder die Bücher, die für uns relevant sind, müssen zurückgegeben werden.

(Ist der Zeitungsartikel jetzt für uns relevant oder nicht?)

Das sollte man vermeiden, hier z.B. dadurch, dass man die beiden Nomen tauscht.

Grundsätzlich sollte man im Interesse einer klaren Sprache solche Konstruktionen sowieso vermeiden, denn selbst wenn man die obigen Regeln befolgt und damit so viel Klarheit wie möglich herstellt, ist unklar, was gemeint ist:

1. Was ist eigentlich "relevant für uns"?
2. Muss ich die Dinger (eins oder beide?) auch zurückgeben, wenn sie für mich (eins davon oder beide?) nicht relevant sind?

Wie oben gezeigt, kann man manchmal durch die Wahl einer anderen Konjunktion (*entweder...oder* oder *sowohl...als auch*) oder ein passendes Pronomen (*beide*) zusätzliche Klarheit herstellen.

Answer (score 4):

Eine [ähnliche Frage](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/53029/relative-pronouns-for-und-and-oder-with-two-singular-nouns?rq=1) gibt es bereits. In den Antworten wird aber nicht auf die Frage nach der "offiziell richtigen Form" eingegangen.

---

Eine "offizielle", "korrekte" oder "richtige" Form gibt es nicht. Wer oder was sollte diese auch bestimmen?

Betrachtet man deskriptiv die Möglichkeiten, die verwendet werden, dann stößt man auf unterschiedlichste Formen (wie du in deiner Frage auch herausgearbeitet hast). Was dort als "richtig" wahrgenommen wird, liegt im Ohr des Betrachters.

Präskriptive Vorgaben* gibt es in Form des [amtlichen Regelwerks des Rats der deutschen Rechtschreibung](https://grammis.ids-mannheim.de/rechtschreibung/), ein Pendant in Sachen Grammtik und Syntax gibt es nicht.

---

*diese beziehen sich aber nicht auf "Privatpersonen"

Comment: Sind Vorgaben immer präskriptiv? ;)

Comment: Die "ähnliche Frage" geht leider überhaupt nicht auf die "Bindungsstärke" zwischen Relativsatz und zugehörigem Nomen relativ zur Bindungsstärke zwischen durch Konjunktion verbundenen Nomen relativ zum Verb ein (ist auch kein Duplikat wg. Sprache).

Comment: Ich denke, wer hier sagt "es gibt keine Regeln", macht es sich ein bißchen zu einfach. Es gibt sehr wohl Kongruenzregeln, und es gibt sehr wohl Regeln, die aus der Kongruenz ableiten, auf was genau sich ein Relativsatz oder ein Verb beziehen. Dass man selbst unter Einhaltung dieser Regeln Mehrdeutigkeiten in der Sprache produzieren kann, ist ein anderes Problem. Im Zweifelsfall gilt die [Grund-]Regel "drücke dich deutlich und unmissverständlich aus".

Comment: @tofro: Du sprichst da ein Grundproblem jeder Sprache an: einerseits gibt es Regeln, was man wie zu verstehen aht, andererseits kann man auch den Anspruch erheben, sich so auszudrücken, daß der Adressat - unabhängig von den Regeln - es auch versteht. Die Frage ist halt: will ich "korrekt" sein, ohne Rücksicht auf Verluste (und wenns der andere nicht versteht ist er selber schuld) oder will ich verstanden werden, egal, was die Regeln besagen? Beides wirft seine Probleme auf und einen Königsweg gibt es nicht.

Comment: @tofro Gute Kommentare, ich lasse die Antwort mal trotzdem stehen..

Comment: @bakunin Du stellst es dar, als würde man nicht mehr verstanden werden, wenn man sich an Regeln hielte. In Wirklichkeit ist es genau andersherum: Regeln sind eben genau dafür da, damit man eine gemeinsame Grundlage für die Verständigung hat. Genau dann, wenn nicht regelkonform formuliert wird, treten Missverständnisse auf.

Comment: @tofro: dann habe ich mich offenbar nicht klar genug ausgedrückt: die von Dir angesprochene "Grundregel: drücke dich [...] unmißverständlich aus" ist - und darauf wollte ich hinaus - was grundsätzlich anderes als "drücke Dich so aus, wie es Regel 4711 im Duden vorsieht". Letzteres mag zwar die Grundlage der Normierung sein, aber wenn ich weiß, daß mein Gegenüber es nicht versteht, dann ist es eben "trotz formaler Richtigkeit falsch". *Das* habe ich versucht, auszudrücken.

Comment: @bakunin Dann hast du die Philosophie hinter (z.B. 4711) wahrscheinlich falsch verstanden. Die Grundregel der Sprache "Drücke dich unmissverständlich aus" soll eben durch Regel 4711 definiert werden - Regel 4711 ist (idealerweise) nur eine der Handreichungen, die sagen, wie man das am besten tut.  Wir können uns darauf einigen, dass ein Regelwerk, das retrospektiv ein lebendiges Ding wie eine Sprache in Regeln fassen will, immer Löcher und Mehrdeutigkeiten haben kann, oder sogar muß.  ...

Comment: ... Mehrdeutigkeit entsteht i.A. *trotz* Einhalten der Regeln, meistens nicht *wegen* (wenn das so wäre, wäre wohl die Regel falsch). Schließlich muß eine Sprache eben auch gerade die Möglichkeit bieten, Unsinn zu verzapfen oder mit vielen Worten nix Eindeutiges - sonst könnten sie Politiker oder Komödianten ja nicht benutzen (wer welches Feature braucht, darfst du dir selbst aussuchen...).